# puzzled in a "Or" condition clause in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

It's a problem I encountered in the work and I simplify it as follows:
First, is the testcase

```
create table A_TESTB
(
  A VARCHAR2(10),
  B VARCHAR2(10)
);

insert into A_TESTB (A, B)
values ('1', '2');
insert into A_TESTB (A, B)
values ('1', '3');
insert into A_TESTB (A, B)
values ('1', '4');
commit;

SQL> select * from a_testb;

A          B
---------- ----------
1          2
1          3
1          4
```

then,I use sql like below

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM (SELECT '10' TESTTYPE, T.* FROM A_TESTB T) W
  3   WHERE (W.A = '1' OR 1 = 2)
  4     AND W.TESTTYPE = '999999';

TESTTYPE A          B
-------- ---------- ----------
10       1          2
10       1          3
10       1          4
```

The question is : I have used the condition `AND W.TESTTYPE = '999999'` to filter， and my expecting resultset should be empty,but it seems that the condition doesn't work ,the secret maybe from `OR`, but why doesn't it work?

Comment: what if your and is `W.B = '99999'`? I suspect the constant isn't getting handled correctly rather than the OR causing problems, but I don't have oracle available to do any tests.

Comment: if my and is "W.B ='99999'" the resultset is empty,but I need
"W.TESTTYPE" rather than "W.B"

Comment: Can you post the execution plan, including predicate filters, for the query?

Comment: Run that in SqlPlus using set serveroutput on set echo on and post the results

Answer (score 4):

My result set is empty!

I am using

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

NO ROWS RETURNED for your query using TOAD release 10.5.0.41:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT '10' TESTTYPE, T.*
          FROM A_TESTB T) W
 WHERE (W.A = '1' OR 1 = 2) AND W.TESTTYPE = '999999';
```

I run it also in SQL*Plus, just to be 100% sure:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM (SELECT '10' TESTTYPE, T.* FROM A_TESTB T) W
  3   WHERE (W.A = '1' OR 1 = 2)
  4      AND W.TESTTYPE = '999999';

No rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I ran a test in SQL Server and also received no rows returned.

Comment: Works as expected for me too; SQL Developer to Oracle 10.2.0.5 under Solaris.

Comment: my session is
SQL> SELECT * FROM v$version;
 
BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Personal Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE 9.2.0.1.0 Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

I can 100% get the 3 rows in my environment,so where's the problem?

Comment: Probably a bug that got fixed in a patchset. If you have support, try to patch to 9.2.0.8 (terminal patchset for 9iR2) or upgrade to 10gR2/11gR2